# Class with no pointer data members- copy constructor == assignment operator?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, deep-copy

If your class does not have any data members declared using pointers, does the copy constructor always contain the same code as the assignment operator? and if not, why not?

EDIT think I need some code to explain what I mean:

```
class A{
public:
    A();
    A(const A& a);
    A& operator=(const A& a);

private:
    int a;
    double b;
};

//Copy constructor
A::A(const A& src){
    a = src.a;
    b = src.b;
}

//Assignment operator
A& A::operator=(const A& src){
    //Because none of the data members are pointers- the code in here 
    //would be the same as the copy constructor?

    //Could I do:
    a = src.a;
    b = src.b;
    //?
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the compiler-generated copy-ctor/assignment-operator?

Comment: Do you have answer for the question when the class *contains* pointers? Is the copy-constructor always same as the assignment operator, in that case?

Comment: No, for one because copy-construction and assignment aren't the same thing. An assignment is done with a lhs that is *already constructed* in one form or another. The object that is the target of copy-construction isn't yet-constructed (thats point of the constructor to begin with). And pointers or not, they have *nothing* to do with this. Copy-construction and assignment are *not* the same.

Comment: Implemented as you've shown it, the *compiler* hasn't generated that copy-constructor; *you did*. `a` and `b` are default-constructed *before* entering the copy-ctor body where their assignment operators would then fire. If your example were accurate to what the compiler generates for default copy-ctors, they would be in an *initializer list*; not assigned in the body of the ctor. Your assignment operator is an accurate model, however.

Comment: The comment in your assignment operator should say - because none of the data members are pointers or type class object, and your class has no base classes.  The common term for this type of class is POD - Plain Old Data.

Answer (score 3):

No, the assignment operators of the members are involved:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

struct X {
    X() { std::cout << "construct" << std::endl; }
    X(const X&) { std::cout << "copy construct" << std::endl;  }
    X& operator = (const X&) {
        throw std::logic_error("assignment");
    }
};

struct Y {
    X x;
};

int main() {
    Y y0;
    Y y1(y0);
    y1 = y0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 this is per the standard. The default assignment operator performs a member-by-member assignment operation of each member variable with a lhs of said-same that is *already constructed*. The default copy-ctor performs member-by-member copy-construction, where the lhs in each is about-to-be-constructed (i.e. it isn't constructed yet). All roads eventually lead to the the base difference between copy-construction and assignment. Constructors do just that: construct. Assignment has a lhs that is already constructed. Nice sample, btw.

Answer (score 1):

A copy constructor operates on raw memory.
So if it references a member variable that has not been set yet,
then it is referencing uninitialized memory.

An assignment operator operates on memory already containing a constructed object.
So all member variables are initialized before the assignment operator starts.

If your assignment operator does not examine any member variables,
then the copy ctor code would be the same.
But note that using a member variable assignment operator in your assignment operator
might reference data you don't know about.